# Cannot read property Vue js

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

Я хочу  сделать систему лайков, но в консоли такая ошибка 
связанная со строчкой  `this.totallike = response.data.post.like`

```
Cannot read property 'like' of undefined
```

Когда я нажимаю, чтобы лайкнуть, то `POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/like/undefined 500 (Internal Server Error)`

И еще такая `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500`

С Vue.JS не знаком, но срочная нужна реализация на нём. Брал с этого источника

https://www.codechief.org/article/simple-like-system-in-laravel-6-using-vue-js

LikeComponent.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <p id="success"></p>
       <a href="http://"><i @click.prevent="likePost" class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>({{ totallike }})</a>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props:['article'],
        data(){
            return {
                totallike:'',
            }
        },
        methods:{
            likePost(){
                axios.post('/blog/like/'+this.post,{post:this.post})
                .then(response =>{
                    this.getlike()
                    $('#success').html(response.data.message)
                })
                .catch()
            },
            getlike(){
                axios.post('/like',{post:this.post})
                .then(response =>{
                    this.totallike = response.data.post.like
                })
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.getlike()
        }
    }
</script>
```

web

```
Route::any('/blog/article/{slug?}','BlogController@article')->name('article');

Route::post('/like','BlogController@getlike');
Route::post('/blog/like/{id}','BlogController@like');
```

BlogController

```
   public function getlike(Request $request)
    {
        $article = Article::find($request->article);
        var_dump($article);
        return response()->json([
            'article'=>$article,
        ]);
    }

  public function like(Request $request)
{
    $article = Article::find($request->article);
    $value = $article->like;
    $article->like = $value+1;
    $article->save();
    return response()->json([
        'message'=>'Thanks',
    ]);
}
```

article blade

```
<like-component :post="{{ $article->id }}"></like-component>
```

Comment: почему `.post.like`, если в контроллере `'article'=>$article,`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот целостный рабочий пример, включая роутинг, контроллер и компоненты.

[image: Система лайков Laravel + Vue]

`routes/web.php`

```php
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::prefix('blog')
    ->name('blog.')
    ->group(function () {
        Route::get('articles', 'Blog\\BlogController@index')
            ->name('list');

        Route::get('article/{article}', 'Blog\\BlogController@show')
            ->name('article');

        Route::post('article/{article}/like', 'Blog\\BlogController@likeAnArticle')
            ->name('article.like');
    });
```

`BlogController.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Blog;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Blog\Article;

/**
 * Class BlogController
 * @package App\Http\Controllers\Blog
 */
class BlogController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $articles = Article::all();

        return response()
            ->json(compact('articles'));
    }

    /**
     * @param Article $article
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function show(Article $article)
    {
        return response()
            ->json(compact('article'));
    }

    /**
     * @param Article $article
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function likeAnArticle(Article $article)
    {
        $article->increment('likes', 1);

        return response()
            ->json(compact('article'));
    }
}
```

`ArticlesComponent.vue`

```vue
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <article-item
                :article="article"
                :key="`article_${article.id}`"
                v-for="article in articles"
                v-if="articles.length">
        </article-item>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  import ArticleComponent from "./ArticleComponent";

  export default {
    name: "ArticlesComponent",
    components: {
      'article-item': ArticleComponent
    },
    props: {
      loadUrl: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      }
    },
    data() {
      return {
        articles: []
      }
    },
    methods: {
      load() {
        axios.get(this.loadUrl)
          .then(response => response.data)
          .then(data => this.articles = data.articles);
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      this.load();
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

`ArticleComponent.vue`

```js
<template>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <h2 v-text="`Article no. ${article.id}`"></h2>
        <article-like :article="article"></article-like>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  import ArticleLikeComponent from "./ArticleLikeComponent";

  export default {
    name: "ArticleComponent",
    components: {
      'article-like': ArticleLikeComponent
    },
    props: {
      article: {
        type: Object,
        required: true
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

`ArticleLikeComponent.vue`

```js
<template>
    <span class="like-btn" @click="like" v-html="`<i class='fa fa-thumbs-up'></i> ${article.likes}`"></span>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      article: {
        type: Object,
        required: true
      }
    },
    data() {
      return {
        likes: {
          count: 0
        }
      }
    },
    methods: {
      like() {
        axios
          .post(`/blog/article/${this.article.id}/like`)
          .then(r => r.data.article)
          .then(article => this.article = article);
      }
    },
    name: "ArticleLikeComponent",

  }
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
  span.like-btn {
    cursor: pointer !important;
  }
</style>
```

`main.blade.php`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>Blog Articles</title>

  <!-- Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Styles -->
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/7e87b4c597.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="solutions" class="container">
    <articles-component load-url="{{ route('blog.list') }}"></articles-component>
  </div>

  <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>

</body>

</html>
```